# Why is the C++ debugger stepping into external codes in VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void reverse(string s){
    if(s.length()==0){ //base case
        return;
    }

    string ros=s.substr(1);
    reverse(ros);
    cout<<s[0];
}

int main(){
    reverse("binod");
    
}
```

[debugger_img_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OijmE.png)

[debugger_img_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4uKs.png)

PFA,
The debugger is supposed to step into the reverse() function. But it is opening these external codes.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the first line of the target function and run till it breaks?

Comment: It still steps into these tabs, but 'step out and then step into' works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The debugger is stepping into the `std::string(const char*)` constructor. Your code calls this implicitly before calling `reverse` because you pass `"binod"` (which effectively has type `const char*`) to a function expecting a `std::string`.

There's nothing wrong here, it's not the wrong function, just a function you didn't realise was being called. Just step out and then step in again.

Side note: Visual Studio's debugger has the 'Just My Code!' feature which, when enabled, means the debugger only steps into code you wrote. Can be a useful time saver.

Comment: How to do that in VS Code? [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72894675/how-to-enable-just-my-code-setting-in-vscode-debugger)