# How to enable justMyCode in VS Code C++ debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Whenever I am debugging C++ program functions, sometimes it steps into libraries/constructors. I want to debug 'just my code'. There are direct settings for this feature in Visual Studio. But I am unable to find it in Visual Studio Code settings.

**{ } launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: g++.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
              {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
              }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
          }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be enabled by default. However, For this, you need to change the `launch.json` file. Inside the `launch.json` file you have to set "`justMyCode`" to `true`.

```
"justMyCode":true
```

put it under `request` or any place inside configuration.

Comment: Ok, But The debugger is still stepping into the library/constructor (if just my code is enabled by default). 
And about the solution, do I need to add a separate configuration in launch.json?

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980448/how-to-disable-just-my-code-setting-in-vscode-debugger)

Comment: Yes, give it a go. create another conf called for example (test) and set the value of justMyCode inside

Comment: I think this answer is wrong, `justMyCode` does not apply to C++ debugging.

Answer (score 1):

So far, there is no option for `justMyCode` in VS Code C++ Debugger (GDB v12.1). There is no mention of `justMyCode` in the C++ Debugger [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug).

When you add `justMyCode` (feature for python debugger) and `skipFiles` (feature for node.js debugger) in **launch.json** in VS Code, it gives an error.

> Property justMyCode is not allowed.

For now, The only way to skip external codes is, just by doing 'Step into and then Step out'.

Answer (score 1):

For gdb, you can use:

```json
"setupCommands": [
  {
    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing\nskip -gfi /usr/include/c++/*/*/*\nskip -gfi /usr/include/c++/*/*\nskip -gfi /usr/include/c++/*",
    "ignoreFailures": true
  }
],
```

Or you can create `~/.gdbinit` file with:

```
skip -gfi /usr/include/c++/*/*/*
skip -gfi /usr/include/c++/*/*
skip -gfi /usr/include/c++/*
```